# Own a subdomain on meteor.com

Tags: meteor

If I publish my app to a subdomain, eg: spartan.meteor.com do I own the subdomain or can some other user take it from me? If I can own it, is there some documentation around it?

Comment: See @colllin's answer as this has been addressed.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can set a deploy password for your app.

```
$ meteor deploy -P spartan.meteor.com
```

Any future deploy (or request for logs) will require the same password.

Answer (score 13):

As an update:

As of Meteor v0.7.1, this is no longer relevant.  If you don't yet have a meteor developer account, `meteor deploy <site>` will prompt you for your email address and send you a link to create a password.  Then they have some functionality around authorizing other users to collaborate on your app.

Comment: Related docs can be found here: https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/02/25/meteor-developer-accounts

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is now:

```
meteor deploy <site> [--password]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question also asked if there was any documentation. It is available here: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteordeploy

It covers additional things like changing the password. It specifies `--password` as the command-line option, but `-P` appears to still work. It alludes to forthcoming Meteor accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question was about the subdomain (SPARTAN) in meteor deploy domain (SPARTAN.METEOR.COM) being your property or not.
I've made a deploy half year ago and it's still there, so I think Meteor recycles the subdomains from time to time, but they give you a very good long time for sure.